# Rspec: mocked ENV vars are visible in examples, but not in application code

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, environment-variables

**TL;DR - My ruby class can read an ENV var in real life. Rspec examples can read a mocked ENV var. But my ruby class can't read the same mocked ENV var in tests. What am I doing wrong?**

The full story:

I have this ruby class that uses an (optional) ENV var to set a user's flavor, defaulting to 'vanilla':

```
class MyConfigger
  attr_reader :flavor

  def load_config
    @flavor = ENV['MY_FLAVOR'] || 'vanilla'
    self
  end
end
```

This works, as tested in IRB:

```
% irb -I lib -r my_configger
irb(main):001:0> MyConfigger.new.load_config.flavor
=> "vanilla"


% MY_FLAVOR=cherry irb -I lib -r my_configger
irb(main):001:0> MyConfigger.new.load_config.flavor
=> "cherry"
```

However, it does not see the mocked ENV var when I run tests on it. The first two pass, as expected, but the last one fails, indicating that my app code is not seeing the mocked ENV var:

```
RSpec.describe MyConfigger do
  let(:config) { described_class.new }

  before { config.load_config }

  describe '.flavor' do
    subject { config.flavor }

    context 'with defaults' do
      it { is_expected.to eq 'vanilla' }
    end

    context 'when MY_ENV=chocolate' do
      before { allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('MY_FLAVOR').and_return('chocolate') }

      it "ENV['MY_FLAVOR'] in example is chocolate" do # This test passes.
        expect(ENV['MY_FLAVOR']).to eq 'chocolate'
      end

      it 'config.flavor is chocolate' do  #  <<---------------- THIS TEST FAILS
        is_expected.to eq 'chocolate'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
MyConfigger
  .flavor
    with defaults
      is expected to eq "vanilla"
    when MY_ENV=chocolate
      ENV['MY_FLAVOR'] in example is chocolate
      config.flavor is chocolate (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) MyConfigger.flavor when MY_ENV=chocolate config.flavor is chocolate
     Failure/Error: is_expected.to eq 'chocolate'

       expected: "chocolate"
            got: "vanilla"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/lib/my_configger_fail_spec.rb:25:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

3 examples, 1 failure
```

I've tried *many* variations of `ENV['MY_FLAVOR']` vs `ENV.fetch('MY_FLAVOR', 'vanilla')` etc, and none succeeds.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**This problem has NOTHING to do with ENV vars, and little to do with mocking. It really boils down to order of execution of `before` blocks in rspec.**

After much hair-pulling and asking for a second set of eyes from a coworker, we realized the `allow(ENV)...` mock in the deep `before` block was being executed *after* the `before` block at the top of the test suite.

This is a bit counterintuitive (to me at least) since we're so used to deep `let` assignments overriding upper `let` assignments.

In the end, I moved the `allow` command up to the initial `before` block, to ensure that it runs before `load_config` gets called. (This required using a variable for the mocked value, so it doesn't break the first test for the default 'vanilla' value.)

```
RSpec.describe MyConfigger do
  let(:config) { described_class.new }
  let(:flavor) { nil }

  before {
    allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('MY_FLAVOR').and_return(flavor) #   <<------ MOVED UP HERE
    config.load_config
  }

  describe '.flavor' do
    subject { config.flavor }

    context 'with defaults' do
      it { is_expected.to eq 'vanilla' }
    end

    context 'when MY_ENV=chocolate' do
      let(:flavor) { 'chocolate' }

      it "ENV['MY_FLAVOR'] in example is chocolate" do 
        expect(ENV['MY_FLAVOR']).to eq 'chocolate'
      end

      it 'config.flavor is chocolate' do  # This test now passes! :-)
        is_expected.to eq 'chocolate'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I have happy tests:

```
MyConfigger
  .flavor
    with defaults
      is expected to eq "vanilla"
    when MY_ENV=chocolate
      ENV['MY_FLAVOR'] in example is chocolate
      config.flavor is chocolate

3 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: Before(:each) blocks and let assignments are both usually executed in the order they are encountered. There’s no difference in ordering; it’s just that blocks run in sequence can often have side effects that may impact other contexts or bypass scope gates, while sequential assignments (which simple #let statements often resemble) generally won’t.

Comment: You may be right about the order of `before` blocks, but `let` assignments are absolutely hierarchical. That is, deeper `let` assignments will always override higher-level `let` assignments. This probably matches up well with your assertion that they are executed in the order they are encountered in a lot of cases, but doesn't tell the whole story.